# Prime ng paginator how to return to the previous page

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a list of documents. Divided into 3 pages. Imagine a situation, the user is on page 2. deletes all documents on this page. How to move it to 1 page after that (forward)

```
 <p-paginator [showCurrentPageReport]="true" [rows]="ten" [totalRecords]="lengthDoc" (onPageChange)="transitionPage($event)"></p-paginator>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fm4s.png)

Comment: Hi, so, what is your question ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user deletes all documents on the second page, you must refresh data of the grid. But if you process paging in the server you must send a paging state when refreshing data.